# Google Script urlFetchApp Post failing calling Jira Tempo worklogs

Tags: google-apps-script, post, jira-rest-api, urlfetch

I trying to write a google script to query Jira Tempo worklogs.

This is what I have so far:

```
function postDataForAPI() {

  var payloadData = {
    "taskKey" :   [] 
  };
  payloadData.taskKey.push("AA-123");

  var payload = Utilities.jsonStringify(payloadData);
  

  var url = "https://api.tempo.io/core/4/worklogs/search";
  var digestfull = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("digest"); //get username and password (base64 encrypted)

  var options = { "Accept":"application/json", 
              "Content-Type":"application/json", 
              "method": "POST",
              "headers": {"Authorization": digestfull},
              "muteHttpExceptions": true,
              "payload" : payload
             };

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  if (resp.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    Browser.msgBox("Error retrieving data for url " + url + ":" + resp.getContentText());
    return "";
  }  
  else {
    return resp.getContentText();
  }  
  
}
```

When I execute the above it fails.

If I use curl then I can successfully make the request (I think this is essentially the same POST):

```
curl -u "username:password"  -X POST https://api.tempo.io/rest/tempo-timesheets/4/worklogs/search -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"taskKey":["AA-123"]}'
```

Making GET requests against the same API works fine:

```
function getDataForAPI() {

  var url = "https://api.tempo.io/core/4/worklogs/101112";
  var digestfull = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("digest"); //get username and password (base64 encrypted)

  var options = { "Accept":"application/json", 
              "Content-Type":"application/json", 
              "method": "GET",
              "headers": {"Authorization": digestfull},
              "muteHttpExceptions": true
             };

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  if (resp.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    Browser.msgBox("Error retrieving data for url " + url + ":" + resp.getContentText());
    return "";
  }  
  else {
    return resp.getContentText();
  }  
  
}
```

So I'm confident it is not Authorisation (GET request succeeds). The curl request succeeds and appears to be in the same form as the google script and yet the google script POST fails.

What do I have wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script.

  ```
    curl -u "username:password"  -X POST https://api.tempo.io/rest/tempo-timesheets/4/worklogs/search -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"taskKey":["AA-123"]}'
  ```

#### Modification points:

- It seems that `"Accept":"application/json"` is not used in the sample curl command.
- `"Content-Type":"application/json"` is required to be included in the request header. But, at UrlFetchApp, the property of `contentType` can be used.
- `Utilities.jsonStringify` has been deprecated. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#deprecated-methods_1)

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function postDataForAPI() {
  var payloadData = { "taskKey": [] };
  payloadData.taskKey.push("AA-123");
  var url = "https://api.tempo.io/core/4/worklogs/search";
  var digestfull = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("digest");
  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "headers": { "Authorization": digestfull },
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payloadData)
  };
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  if (resp.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    Browser.msgBox("Error retrieving data for url " + url + ":" + resp.getContentText());
    return "";
  }
  else {
    return resp.getContentText();
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- When I saw your provided curl command, it seems that the URL is different. The sample curl command uses `https://api.tempo.io/rest/tempo-timesheets/4/worklogs/search`. But your script uses `https://api.tempo.io/core/4/worklogs/search`. I'm worried about this difference. So if the above-modified script didn't work, please check the URL again.
- The request of this modified script is the same as the sample curl command. But if an error occurs, please check each value like `digestfull` and `payloadData`, again.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated as you indicated. 
1.) The URL was a mistake in my original post (it is built by another function and when I simplified the functions for posting I copied the wrong value). I've edited above for consistency.
2.) I reviewed the values of digestFull and payloadData and they are entirely consistent with the curl command.
I am still getting an empty response object.
I am currently investigating network issues.

Comment: @Brett Ansley Thank you for replying. I think that at least, the request of my modified script is the same with the sample curl command. So in your current situation, can you confirm each value and `digestfull` again. For example, from `I reviewed the values of digestFull and payloadData and they are entirely consistent with the curl command.`. in the curl command, `-u "username:password"` is used. This is the basic authorization. But I cannot see the structure of `digestfull`. So I'm worried about this. Can you provide the value of `digestfull` by removing your personal information?

Comment: Of course: `digestfull` == `Basic XXX` where XXX is a base64encoded representation of username:password. So the `headers` parameter  ends up looking like this: `{Authorization=Basic XXX}`.
And `payload` looks like this: `{"taskKey":["WAT-11"]}` 
I've also confirmed with our infrastructure team that there are known networking issues between Google sheets and the jira server, I just waiting to confirm this applies to POST commands.

Comment: @Brett Ansley Thank you for replying. About the authorization header, I think that in that case, my proposed script is the same with the curl command. And, from `I've also confirmed with our infrastructure team that there are known networking issues between Google sheets and the jira server, I just waiting to confirm this applies to POST commands.`, when this issue is resolved, I think that this modified script works. At that time, please test it again.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me - I really appreciate it.